# Finding implicit method definitions in macro context

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I understand the basic concept of macros in Scala, but currently fail to do this (simple?) job:

- Find all implicit `def`s/`val`s currently visible to the compiler to transform from a given type to another one.

What I'd expect to get is a `List` of `Method` objects or something similar. I already played around with `enclosingImplicits` but always get an empty list and do not really know where to look next.

What do I need to do to get the list I am looking for?

Answer (score 4):

There can be only one implicit from type `A` to `B` in the context (or you get ambigious implicit), so if you want to find it:

```
import reflect.macros.Context, scala.language.experimental.macros

def fImpl(c: Context): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.mirror._         
  println(c.inferImplicitValue(typeOf[Int]))
  c.universe.reify( () )
}
def f = macro fImpl

scala> f
<empty>

scala> implicit val a = 5
a: Int = 5

scala> f
$line24.$read.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.a

scala> implicit val b = 5
b: Int = 5

scala> f //result will be empty, but error printed to the log
error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value a of type => Int
 and value b of type => Int
 match expected type Int
<empty>
```

To find implicit method:

```
def fImpl(c: Context): c.Expr[Unit] = {
      import c.mirror._       
      println(c.inferImplicitValue(typeOf[String => Int]))        
      c.universe.reify( () )
 }
def f = macro fImpl

scala> f
<empty>

scala> implicit def aaa(a: String) = 5
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
aaa: (a: String)Int

scala> "A" : Int
res10: Int = 5

scala> f
{
  ((a: String) => $line47.$read.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.aaa(a))
}
```

If `silent` parameter is `false` (`true` by default), `TypecheckException` will be thrown in case of an inference error. So you could analize it to find list of ambigious implicits.

P.S. If type `B` is uncknown - there is no (documented) way to find all implicits using macroses: `openImplicits`/`enclosingImplicits` just looking for implicits being materialized in context of macro-expansion - not for all, that exists in the context. Compiler-plugin may help, but it's not so easy then.

If you really decide to try "compiler-plugin" way - the logic of finding implicits is implemented [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Implicits.scala). [Here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/scala-compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context) you can find compiler's `Context` (not same as macro's) and its `implicitss` field, which contains all implicits in the context (but it's not so trivial to obtain appropriate context).

---

And *I shouldn't tell you* but there is a tricky and unsafe hack to lift from macro `Context` to compiler's level and do what you want:

```
 scala>  def fImpl(c: Context): c.Expr[Unit] = {
 |       val cc = c.asInstanceOf[reflect.macros.contexts.Context]
 |       println(cc.callsiteTyper.context.implicitss.flatten)
 |       c.universe.reify( () )
 |  }
fImpl: (c: reflect.macros.Context)c.Expr[Unit]

scala> def f = macro fImpl

scala> f //I've defined aaaaaaaa etc. implicits while playing with that
List(aaaaaaaa: ?, lllllllllllllllllllllzzzz: ?, lllllllllllllllllllll: ?, lllllllllllllllllllll: ?, aaa: ?, aaa: ?, aaa: ?, aaa: ?, aaa: ?, aaa: ?, b: ?, a: ?, macros: ?, RuntimeClassTag:
```

Anyway, you have to analize a list of [`ImplicitInfo`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/scala-compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitInfo) to obtain implicits you're looking for and it may not be trivial, as you can see from [`Analizer`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Implicits.scala)'s sources, but at least it's possible to get approximate result, which may be fine for your needs. But again, it's better to do that **very very very careful**, as structures you working with are mutable and methods are not pure. And, as @Eugene Burmako noticed, this solution doesn't give you implicits from companion object.

Comment: I read the question as saying the source type was given and the target wasn't, in which case I don't think there's a good solution.

Comment: @Travis Brown In that case, I don't even see any, except compiler-plugin.

Comment: @Travis Brown actually there is non-documented unsafe way to do that (as long as any other compiler-dependent tricks) with macro :) My example gives all possible implicits, so it needs to be additionally analised (which is also tricky)

Comment: Maybe @Eugene Burmako knows potential risks of using `callsiteTyper.context.implicitss` from macro (let's forget about my criminal typecast)

Comment: I don't think that Context.implicitss includes stuff from the entire implicit scope. Iirc, the lookup for implicits declared in companion objects is done separately. Also, the information itself might be perfectly fine, but trying to make sense of it on your own might be extremely hard since in the compiler there's a 1.5kloc file dedicated to exactly that. All in all, you'll have to experimentally see for yourself whether this hack works for your use case, but be sure to check crazy situations to make sure you don't miss anything.

Comment: Also, the biggest risk of hacks like this is that they are certainly not going to be portable to scala.meta (or, most likely, even expressible in scala.meta at all), so if you plan to be compatible with scala.meta in the future, that'll be a problem.

Comment: Finally, I'm not sure whether you can implement this logic in a compiler plugin. The information about lexical scopes (including lexically scoped implicits) is only available during the `typer` phase, and traditional plugins can't inject there.

Comment: @Eugene Burmako, thanks!  So as a conclusion I believe it might be useful to introspect implicits for some research, but definitely not recommended for a real macro-based library. Btw, it's really not working for implicits from companion object.

Comment: @Eugene Burmako, am I understanding right that compiler-plugin still allows to get implicits imported from other build-units using smthng like `global.analyzer.rootContext(global.currentUnit).implicitss` ?

Comment: Not sure, but I think that rootContext(...) won't see imports declared at the top of the file - just the basic ones (Predef, scala, etc).

Comment: @Eugene Burmako yeah, looks like that, thanks anyway :)